# Error in installing chilkat-9.5.0-python-2.7-macosx

Tags: chilkat

Using 'python installChilkat.py' command as per the instillation instructions produces the following error:

This Python version 2.7
This system: Darwin
This processor: x86_64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "installChilkat.py", line 87, in 
    spDir = site.getusersitepackages()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getusersitepackages'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post a work-around to the problem as no one was able to answer the question. Instead of using site.getusersitepackages()/site.getsitepackages(), use get_python_lib() from distutils.sysconfig.